# (Error performing setData, INVALID_ARGUMENT: The value of property "video" is longer than 1048487 bytes., null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I'm using firebase database, i upload the video is convert the base64 string & it cannot convert

Comment: add your code as text not as image, and also add the error as text not as image

Comment: try to upload it to firebase storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Firestore, and in Firestore there is a size limit for each document which is 1mb, the `video` property that you are adding to the document is greater than that size limit, that's why you get that error.

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document    1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

You need to add the video to firebase storage, then add the reference URL to firestore.